# How to control route access using Scope in Vue js and Laravel Passport?

Tags: vue.js, scope, single-page-application, laravel-passport

I'm building an SPA with Vue js and Laravel and I've created my Auth system using Laravel Passport. There are two types of users in my application, candidates and employers. When a user registers they will have a role of either candidate or employer and I created two scopes called candidate and employer. So a user with the scope candidate should only be able to see the routes for a candidate and a user with a scope of employer should only be able to see the routes for employers. Makes sense.

The issue I'm having is when I try to go to /api/employer/profile/create in Postman using a user with scope of candidate, I get `403
Invalid scope(s) provided.`
which is good this is what I want. But when I log in as this user with scope candidate and go to this route in the browser /employer/profile/create I'm able to see the page.

Why does it work in Postman but not in my app?

Here is my api.php:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function() {

   Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
   Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('profile', 'AuthController@profile');
    });

});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'candidate'], function() {

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

        Route::post('profile', function() {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Candidate access',
                'status_code' => 200
            ], 200);
        })->middleware('scope:candidate');

        Route::post('profile/create', function() {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Candidate access',
                'status_code' => 200
            ], 200);
        })->middleware('scope:candidate');

        Route::resource('profile', 'CandidateProfileController');

    });

});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'employer'], function() {

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

        Route::post('profile', function() {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Employer access',
                'status_code' => 200
            ], 200);
        })->middleware('scope:employer');

    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

        Route::post('profile/create', function() {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Employer access',
                'status_code' => 200
            ], 200);
        })->middleware('scope:employer');

    });

});
```

And router.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from './views/Home';
import Login from './views/authentication/Login';
import Register from './views/authentication/Register';
import Forms from './views/Forms';
import Dashboard from './views/Dashboard';
import Admin from './views/Admin';
import CandidateProfileIndex from './views/candidate/profile/ProfileIndex';
import CandidateProfileCreate from './views/candidate/profile/ProfileCreate';
import EmployerProfileCreate from './views/employer/profile/ProfileCreate';
import ResetPassword from './views/authentication/ResetPassword';
import * as auth from './services/auth_service.js';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home
    },

    {
        path: '/admin',
        component: Admin,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'dashboard',
                component: Dashboard,
                meta: {
                    breadcrumb: 'Admin'
                },
            },

            {
                path: '/candidate/profile',
                name: 'candidate-profile-index',
                component: CandidateProfileIndex,
                meta: {
                    breadcrumb: 'My Profile'
                },
            },

            {
                path: '/candidate/profile/create',
                name: 'candidate-profile-create',
                component: CandidateProfileCreate,
                meta: {
                    breadcrumb: 'Create Profile'
                },
            },

            {
                path: '/employer/profile/create',
                name: 'employer-profile-create',
                component: EmployerProfileCreate,
                meta: {
                    breadcrumb: 'Create Profile'
                },
            },
        ],
        beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
            if (!auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                next('/login');
            } else {
                next();
            }
        }
    },

    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login,
        beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
            if (!auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                next();
            } else {
                next('/');
            }
        }
    },

    {
        path: '/register',
        name: 'register',
        component: Register
    },

    {
        path: '/reset-password',
        name: 'resetpassword',
        component: ResetPassword
    },

    {
        path: '/forms',
        name: 'forms',
        component: Forms
    }
]

const router  = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes,
    linkActiveClass: 'active'
});

export default router;
```

UPDATED!

AuthServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::tokensCan([
            'candidate' => 'view candidate routes only',
            'employer' => 'view employer routes only',
        ]);

        Passport::routes();

    }
```

I added the PassportServiceProvider in config/app.php and changed the api driver from token to passport in config/auth.php.

```
'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
```

Here is my auth system code:

```
import {http, httpFile} from './http_service.js';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import store from '../store.js';

export function register(user) {
    return http().post('/auth/register', user);
}

export function login(user) {
    return http().post('/auth/login', user)
        .then(response => {
           if (response.status === 200) {
                setToken(response.data)
           }

           return response.data;
        });
}

function setToken(user) {
    const token = jwt.sign({ user: user }, 'laravelvuespaaskjsdiowtyurweiuwuuwiueoiwuesnmbnmsdsndbs829638628');
    localStorage.setItem('laravel-vue-spa-token', token);
    store.dispatch('authenticate', user.user);
}

export function isLoggedIn() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('laravel-vue-spa-token');
    return token != null;
}

export function logout() {
    http().get('/auth/logout');
    localStorage.removeItem('laravel-vue-spa-token');
}

export function getAccessToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('laravel-vue-spa-token');
    if (!token) {
        return null;
    }

    const tokenData = jwt.decode(token);
    return tokenData.user.access_token;
}

export function getProfile() {
    return http().get('/auth/profile');
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see any code on the Vue side that would tell vue-router about the employer/candidate route restrictions. Once the front-end loads, it's in Vue-router's hands. That's how SPA's work - they don't go back to the server for routing.

Comment: Do you have documentation on this?

Comment: On what specifically?

Comment: Documentation on how to set it up on the Vue side. Take a look above at UPDATED! to see what else I've done. I just took a 6 and half hour course on Laravel, Vue js and Auth system using Laravel Passport and the instructor didn't mention anything about setting something up on the Vue side for Vue-Router, I'm just not sure where to turn to now.

Comment: Try the vue router docs